# Return multiple columns in a GROUP BY query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following table:

```
    tbl_start_times

    id mach_id start_time
    -- ------- ----------
    1  1       00:12
    2  3       05:18
    3  1       03:56
    4  2       01:51
    5  1       12:48
    6  2       00:10
    7  3       09:15
```

I want to return id, mach_id, and MIN(start_time) for each mach_id.

The code:

```
    SELECT mach_id, MIN(start_time) FROM tbl_start_times GROUP BY mach_id
```

Returns this result:

```
    mach_id start_time
    ------- ----------
    1       00:12
    3       05:18
    2       00:10
```

How can I add the id to my result so that I get this?

```
    id mach_id start_time
    -- ------- ----------
    1  1       00:12
    2  3       05:18
    6  2       00:10
```

Comment: Just group by id and mach_Id?

Comment: When you group by `mach_id`, the `id` may not be unique. Are you okay with seeing any one of the possibly many `id`s?

Comment: I want the id from the same row as the value returned by MIN(start_time)

Comment: That's just what I was looking for, Clodoaldo.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this in Postgres:

Using the Postgres specific `distinct on ()` operator:

```
SELECT distinct on (match_id) id, match_id, start_time
FROM tbl_start_times 
ORDER BY match_id, start_time;
```

Or use a window function:

```
with numbered_times as (
    select id, match_id, start_time, 
           row_number() over (partition by match_id order by start_time) as rn
    from tbl_start_times 
) 
select id, match_id, start_time
from numbered_times
where rn = 1;
```

This also lets you easily pick the "second" or "fourth" row rather than only the "first" or "last" when you use distinct on (or a min/max solution)

If multiple rows are the "lowest" (i.e. have the same lowest time for the same match_id) *and* you want to see all of them, use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`

The solution with `distinct on` is usually faster than the corresponding solution using a window function. The window function is standard SQL however and runs on (nearly) all modern DBMS. Both versions are usually faster than solutions using a sub-query or a derived table as only a single pass is required to read the data.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/caa95/5

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with **correlated sub-query** as follows:

```
SELECT id, mach_id, start_time
FROM tbl_start_times tst
WHERE start_time = (SELECT MIN(start time) 
                    FROM tbl_start_times tst2
                    WHERE tst2.mach_id = tst.mach_id)
ORDER BY id
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a3cff/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.id , t.mach_id, t.start_time
FROM tbl_start_times t, 
    (SELECT mach_id, MIN(start_time) as start_time
    FROM tbl_start_times 
    GROUP BY mach_id) t1
WHERE t.mach_id=t1.mach_id AND t.start_time=t1.start_time
```